# Converting dask array using np.asarry is very slow

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, dask

I have a folder of about 150 large images (40000x30000x3) ~400MB each, and I want to validate ROIs from an imaging analysis. I was looking to store the file information in a dask array and then index the specific section of the image by converting it to a numpy array.

```
import dask_image.imread
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw
    
lazy_signal = dask_image.imread.imread(os.path.join(path, '*.jpeg'))
    
for roi in rois:
    z, y_range, x_range = roi[:]
    img = lazy_signal.[z,
                       y_range[0]:y_range[1],
                       x_range[0]:x_range[1],
                       :]
    
    img = np.asarray(img)
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    img = img.resize((200, 200))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.ellipse((85, 85, 115, 115), outline = (0, 0, 255), width = 1)
    img.imshow()
```

However, the conversion to an numpy array is taking multiple seconds per roi and the image chunk is only (100, 100, 3). Any idea how to speed this up or just go straight from dask.array to image?

Comment: The access pattern is inefficient but several seconds seems clearly a lot for a `(1,100,100,3)` slice. Did you run out of memory? If so the swap can be used and the whole systems will be much slower (especially with a HDD since the content of the memory will be moved to the slow storage device which are usually >200 times slower)

Comment: Most likely the time is spent loading and decoding the huge jpeg rather than conversion from dask to numpy array. Apparently it's possible to [partially decode jpegs](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/issues/34) but that's probably not happening here.

Comment: `np.asarray(img)` is equivalend to `img.compute()`? You are probably recomputing everything on each loop.

Comment: Dask is only faster when it can leverage parallel computing resources. We don’t know the structure of your files or what `rois` is so diagnosing specific performance issues here isn’t really possible. But likely the problem is the one mdurant pointed out - you’re using a for loop to iterate in real time over some slice of the array which may or may not be aligned with the file chunking scheme. If it’s not aligned with the chunks, then all files and computations relevant to the requested chunks will need to be loaded and computed in each iteration (slow).

Comment: Instead, you should explicitly think about chunking and data layout/locality when designing your job. Chunk the data so it is aligned with the images you want to create, then map the image creation job across chunks and write out the files in parallel.